# Why is my result blank

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to python, I'm using XLRD to read from an excel. I'm attempting to check the value of the first cell of each row against my variable `mid` using the following code

```
import xlrd

file_location="Z:/DASHBOARD/test.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
mid=5348120284087186


for row_count in range(sheet.nrows):
    if (sheet.cell_value(row_count, 0)==mid):
        print sheet.row_values(row_count)
```

When I comment out the `if` statement it runs fine without checking, displaying the rows. With the `if` statement I get no results back. 5348120284087186 is the value in the first cell on multiple lines and the value of `mid`. Is there additional formatting I need to use with xlrd in order to find that value? I've attempted to not use the variable and just use `5348120284087186` as the comparison for the statement with the same results.

Comment: Do you have the correct data type?  Try **print type(sheet.cell_value(row_count, 0)).  I suspect that the input ID is coming as a string.  Comparing it to an integer will get you **False** every time.  Fix it with either quotes around the integer value, or **int(*<value> *)** around the **sheet.cell ...** reference.

Comment: Can you print the value of sheet.cell_value(row_count, 0) and perhaps determine its type.

Comment: The type is `unicode`

Comment: Attempted the fix with int()

`for row_count in range(sheet.nrows):
 if (int(sheet.cell_value(row_count, 0))==mid):
  print sheet.row_values(row_count)`

which resulted in error stating: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Run Date: '`

Comment: What if both cast to `str()`? `if (str(sheet.cell_value(row_count, 0))==str(mid)):`

Comment: I tried this, no errors but still showing blank results

Comment: You need to print the value you are comparing to mid to learn what is going on

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: Attempted the fix with int() for row_count in range(sheet.nrows):

```
if (int(sheet.cell_value(row_count, 0))==mid): 
    print sheet.row_values(row_count)
```

which resulted in error stating:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Run Date: '
```

That means the value in the cell isn't an integer like you thought, but 'Run Date: '.